# extract time between 2 lines

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk

I have a file with data of the form:

```
7/26/2018 10:01:52.084 MULTITHREAD APP It goes to preserve the context of the destination window LAESVEES03ES0301C when setting the origin data DATA_ENTRY
"n lines"
7/26/2018 12:15:51.512 AWT-EventQueue-0 **Protecting** graphical interface
7/26/2018 12:17:00.121 MULTITHREAD APP It goes to preserve the context of the destination window LARTVERT31RT3111C when setting the origin data DATA_ENTRY
7/26/2018 12:52:48.681 MULTITHREAD APP **Unprotecting** graphic interface
"n lines"
7/26/2018 14:00:51.512 AWT-EventQueue-0 **Protecting** graphical interface
7/26/2018 14:35:35.230 MULTITHREAD APP It goes to preserve the context of the destination window LAPEVEBIOMBIOM03C when setting the origin data DATA_ENTRY
7/26/2018 14:52:48.681 MULTITHREAD APP **Unprotecting** graphic interface
"n lines"
7/26/2018 15:00:51.512 AWT-EventQueue-0 **Protecting** graphical interface
7/26/2018 15:11:19.100 MULTITHREAD APP It goes to preserve the context of the destination window LAPEVEPE27PE2701C when setting the origin data DATA_ENTRY
7/26/2018 15:22:48.681 MULTITHREAD APP **Unprotecting** graphic interface
"n lines"
7/26/2018 15:00:51.512 AWT-EventQueue-0 **Protecting** graphical interface
7/26/2018 15:11:19.100 MULTITHREAD APP It goes to preserve the context of the destination window LARTVEIT29IT2901C when setting the origin data DATA_ENTRY
7/26/2018 15:22:48.681 MULTITHREAD APP **Unprotecting** graphic interface
"n lines"
7/26/2018 15:30:53.512 AWT-EventQueue-0 Protecting graphical interface
7/26/2018 15:41:19.100 MULTITHREAD APP It goes to preserve the context of the destination window LAPEVEPE27PE2701C when setting the origin data DATA_ENTRY
7/26/2018 15:49:48.681 MULTITHREAD APP Unprotecting graphic interface
"n lines"
7/26/2018 16:55:35.000 MULTITHREAD APP It goes to preserve the context of the destination window LAPEVEBIOMBIOM03C when setting the origin data DATA_ENTRY
"n lines"
7/26/2018 16:23:00.000 MULTITHREAD APP It goes to preserve the context of the destination window LARTVERT31RT3111C when setting the origin data DATA_ENTRY
"n lines"
7/26/2018 16:31:31.000 MULTITHREAD APP It goes to preserve the context of the destination window LAESVEES03ES0301C when setting the origin data DATA_ENTRY
"n lines"
```

I want to get an exit in this way:
Date,Hour_Start, Hour_End, Windows_APP

for example:

```
7/26/2018,12:15:51.512,12:52:48.681,LARTVERT31RT3111C
7/26/2018,14:00:51.512,14:52:48.681,LAPEVEBIOMBIOM03C
7/26/2018,15:00:51.512,15:22:48.681,LAPEVEPE27PE2701C
7/26/2018,15:00:51.512,15:22:48.681,LARTVEIT29IT2901C
```

I stop here because they start repeating LAPEVEPE27PE2701C,LAPEVEBIOMBIOM03C,LARTVERT31RT3111C and **LAESVEES03ES0301C**( here start )

the file with this data weighs 3.5Mb aprox. and there are many lines

someone could give me a hand how to do it with awk or similar ( perl or bash )

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html is a good place to learn awk and do text processing..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this Perl solution:

```
$ head win_app.dat
7/26/2018 12:15:51.512 AWT-EventQueue-0 **Protecting** graphical interface
7/26/2018 12:17:00.121 MULTITHREAD APP It goes to preserve the context of the destination window LARTVERT31RT3111C when setting the origin data DATA_ENTRY
7/26/2018 12:52:48.681 MULTITHREAD NACAR **Unprotecting** graphic interface
"n lines"
7/26/2018 14:00:51.512 AWT-EventQueue-0 **Protecting** graphical interface
7/26/2018 14:35:35.230 MULTITHREAD APP It goes to preserve the context of the destination window LAPEVEBIOMBIOM03C when setting the origin data DATA_ENTRY
7/26/2018 14:52:48.681 MULTITHREAD NACAR **Unprotecting** graphic interface
"n lines"
7/26/2018 15:00:51.512 AWT-EventQueue-0 **Protecting** graphical interface
7/26/2018 15:11:19.100 MULTITHREAD APP It goes to preserve the context of the destination window LAPEVEPE27PE2701C when setting the origin data DATA_ENTRY

$ perl -lane ' { $x=sprintf("%s,%s",$F[0],$F[1]) if /AWT-EventQueue/ ; $y=sprintf("%s",$F[-7]) if /MULTITHREAD APP/; $z=sprintf("%s",$F[1]) if /MULTITHREAD NACAR/ ; print "$x,$z,$y" if /n lines/ } ' win_app.dat
7/26/2018,12:15:51.512,12:52:48.681,LARTVERT31RT3111C
7/26/2018,14:00:51.512,14:52:48.681,LAPEVEBIOMBIOM03C
7/26/2018,15:00:51.512,15:22:48.681,LAPEVEPE27PE2701C
7/26/2018,15:00:51.512,15:22:48.681,LARTVEIT29IT2901C
7/26/2018,15:30:53.512,15:49:48.681,LAPEVEPE27PE2701C
7/26/2018,15:30:53.512,15:49:48.681,LAPEVEBIOMBIOM03C
7/26/2018,15:30:53.512,15:49:48.681,LARTVERT31RT3111C
7/26/2018,15:30:53.512,15:49:48.681,LAESVEES03ES0301C

$
```

Comment: Hope it works.. consider giving an upvote